Finding Joists Under Triple Layer Sheetrock
I recently purchased a new home and am trying to add some hanging storage to the garage but I'm struggling to locate the joists for my anchors. After trying multiple techniques to find them (knocking, stud finder, magnets) I just started punching nails in a pattern across the ceiling but the two inch nail made it seem like there was solid wood everywhere but only after the nail was almost completely buried.
I removed the cover to the one junction box in the ceiling figuring I could see what was going on and to confirm that it was anchored to a joist, and it looks like the entire ceiling is triple-layer 5/8th sheetrock backed by plywood (either 3/8th or 1/2"). I'm assuming that because there's an apartment above the garage they were trying to provide as much sound/temp insulation as possible with the thick buffer.
I can measure out 16" from the junction box and pray (I can't tell from looking which side of the joist the junction box is anchored to, and I can't confirm they are using 16" spacing), but short of hammering lots of much larger nails in all over the place to try to find the joists, are there any other techniques I might use to find them?
I don't think I trust lag bolts in thin plywood, but is there another anchoring technique/hardware that would work better if I can't reliably hit a joist?

Anchoring/mounting will depend on the amount of hanging weight.  There are long finishing nails, or can use a small(1/8) diameter drill bit if you can find long ones.  Marking with tape the depth of drywall plus plywood will help.  There is a worry with a junction box in the ceiling, there might also be wires/cable on the ceiling top.  Nails/bits and cables should not meet.  An inspection camera uses a small hole that could find joists.

Got pics of the interior of the junction box?

Thanks both of you - I think I'll get a cheap scope (it looks like they're <$40??!) and drill through so I can get a look around. If I don't have any luck I'll post some pics of the junction box interior... it's a little hard to see anything because they blew texturing mud over the ceiling and the box was open when they did that, so everything is coated, but it's exposed enough that you can see what's going on :)
